# How to publish a new orthodontic technique/device?

Tags: dentistry, medical-device, legal

I am not an orthodontist but a physicist. But while discussing a certain orthodontic technique with an experienced board-certified orthodontist (who graduated and practice in the US), it became apparent to me that the technique he was taught (and uses) is quite over-optimistic in its ignorance of the effects of elementary physical principles, which is why it almost always results in a much-less-than-ideal outcome, and it also greatly disturbs and compromises the other satisfactory elements of the bite.

After thinking about the situation, I came up with a quite simple alternative technique to fully control the desired movement, without disturbing the satisfactory areas of the bite.

It might be implemented with existing orthodontic devices which I am familiar with; however it may be enhanced and slightly simplified with a new auxiliary device that I have (conceptually) invented.

Not being a physician, how do I publish this technique under my name?
How can I patent this auxiliary device, when I did not actually built it, but only drew a sketch?
Not that I try to become a millionaire, I just want to prevent others from taking over this idea and charging orthodontists/patients for using it.

Comment: Talk to a medical professor. There are reasons why something has been the case and it's easy to overlook aspects as an outsider (just think of how many people think they know better than Einstein without having studied physics). In case you overlooked something, the professor will help you clarify with that. In case you haven't, she can provide information on how to publish.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because patents and legal aspects of medicine are off-topic here. I suspect Academics.SE to be a better fit, or maybe there is a designated site for patents etc.

Comment: Definitely considered talking to somebody... who would not laugh me off...  however there is the risk that they may claim they were the first to think about it.

Comment: Then produce a physical copy before the visit with them and get someone to verify the date (date and signature of witnesses) That way you have a proof.

Comment: You mean like sign an affidavit in front of a notary public?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't worry too much about protecting my idea. IANAL, but a simple text of someone (Rapt showed me the attached plans at 13/13/1313, Location and Signature) should suffice. If you're really concerned (which I wouldn't be), you can contact a notary or a lawyer. But I would worry whether I found something first before thinking about patents etc.

Comment: I think it has no legal value though. Notary public signature with a date costs less than 5 bucks in my area, that's much less than a lawyer. I am not saying this is such a case, but many multi-million legal fights would have been prevented by such measures.

Comment: Unfortunately, I agree that these questions do not fall under the scope of this site. However there is a [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) site for the patent question and [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) for the question on publishing your results. My 2 cents: get the advice on protecting your idea first and than co-publish a paper with someone from the field (who will review it and maybe give some useful suggestions as well). Best of luck!